# Unable to preview component variant

Tags: jss, experience-editor, experience-analytics

We're looking to set up an A/B test for a JSS component from the Experience Editor.
We made a component variant that uses a different data source item.
We are unable to preview the component variant. The UI can show the version of the component that matches the original data source, but not the variant.

The javascript console has a couple errors. The first is, `Could not find rendering in the HTML loaded from the server`. That error comes from the Placeholder Chrome loading an iframe of the page which should include the component variant. There's an issue, though, where the fields of variant item are not being made available to render.

Is this something people have seen before?

Example component, with fields prop working:

```
{
  "uid": "a5f79bf8-8bc6-43ca-85f2-7e4172a59a49",
  "componentName": "Series-Value-Prop",
  "dataSource": "{F8ED8F6C-9E81-4869-BA4A-6EC227F89E10}",
  "params": {},
  "fields": { ... }
}
```

Example component, from the iframe, no fields prop, and different data source:

```
{
  "uid": "a5f79bf8-8bc6-43ca-85f2-7e4172a59a49",
  "componentName": "Series-Value-Prop",
  "dataSource": "sitecore://{E7F596CF-B2C5-494E-BE10-77C9853CFDF4}?lang=en&ver=0",
  "params": {}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With help from Sitecore Support: JSS versions >15 include a fix for this bug.